# Recursive PostgreSQL query in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

[Here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/) I have found an example of recursive query that fetches all subordinates of a manager:

Here is a table with test data:

```
INSERT INTO employees (
    employee_id,
    full_name,
    manager_id
)
VALUES
    (1, 'Michael North', NULL),
    (2, 'Megan Berry', 1),
    (3, 'Sarah Berry', 1),
    (4, 'Zoe Black', 1),
    (5, 'Tim James', 1),
    (6, 'Bella Tucker', 2),
    (7, 'Ryan Metcalfe', 2),
    (8, 'Max Mills', 2),
    (9, 'Benjamin Glover', 2),
    (10, 'Carolyn Henderson', 3),
    (11, 'Nicola Kelly', 3),
    (12, 'Alexandra Climo', 3),
    (13, 'Dominic King', 3),
    (14, 'Leonard Gray', 4),
    (15, 'Eric Rampling', 4),
    (16, 'Piers Paige', 7),
    (17, 'Ryan Henderson', 7),
    (18, 'Frank Tucker', 8),
    (19, 'Nathan Ferguson', 8),
    (20, 'Kevin Rampling', 8);
```

And here is a query that recursively gets all subdordinates of manager with id = 2.

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
    SELECT
        employee_id,
        manager_id,
        full_name
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        employee_id = 2
    UNION
        SELECT
            e.employee_id,
            e.manager_id,
            e.full_name
        FROM
            employees e
        INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.employee_id = e.manager_id
) SELECT
    *
FROM
    subordinates;
```

Is there a way to implement it with sequelize with reasonable amount of `raw` sql insertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize is not intended to execute complex aggregating or recursive queries using models so you will end up with `sequelize.query` to execute such queries as is:

```js
const subordinates = await sequelize.query('
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
    SELECT
        employee_id,
        manager_id,
        full_name
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        employee_id = $employee_id
    UNION
        SELECT
            e.employee_id,
            e.manager_id,
            e.full_name
        FROM
            employees e
        INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.employee_id = e.manager_id
) SELECT
    *
FROM
    subordinates;', {
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
  bind: {
    employee_id: 2
  }
})
```

Try not to concatenate strings into a result SQL to avoid SQL injections and always try to use `bind` or `replacements` options to substitute needed values.

See [raw queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements)